# Unfair die game

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

> For this task, you're going to play a dice game, but first you must
>   prepare for an overwhelming victory. The game itself is very simple.
>   Both players roll a single die and whoever rolls highest scores a
>   point. (On a tie, both players must reroll until someone scores.)
>
> These aren't standard dice however. Each player can put any positive
>   number on any side of the die as long as the number of sides match and
>   the total of all the chosen numbers are the same. For example, one
>   player might use a six sided die with the numbers [3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6]
>   while the other player uses a six sided die with the numbers [4, 4, 4,
>   4, 4, 4]. The interesting part of this game is that even with the same
>   number of sides and the same total, different dice have different
>   chances of winning. Using the example die, the player with all 4's
>   will win 2/3 of the time.
>
> To prepare for this game, you're investigating different ways of
>   picking the numbers. To do this, write a program that will take an
>   opponent's die and output some die which will win against it more than
>   half the time. If no die satisfies the task requirements, return an
>   empty list.
>
> Input: An enemy's die as a sorted list of integers, one for each face
>   of the opponent's die.
>
> Output: Your die as a list of integers, one for each face of your die
>   or an empty list.
>
> - `winning_die([3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6]) == [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] # Or [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]`
> - `winning_die([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]) == [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5] # Or [5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5]`
> - `winning_die([2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6]`
> - `winning_die([1, 1, 3]) == [1, 2, 2]`

How can I make this faster?

```
import itertools

def winning_die(enemy_die):
    upper = max(enemy_die) + 1
    comb = [i for i in itertools.product(range(1, upper+1), repeat=len(enemy_die)) 
            if sum(i)== sum(enemy_die)]

    for die in comb:
        if win(die, enemy_die):
            return list(die)
    return []

def win(player, enemy):
    return sum(1 if p > e else -1 if p < e else 0 
               for p in player for e in enemy) > 0
```

Comment: You need to implement a function similar to `product` which generates dice with the correct sum without wasting time generating dice that are nowhere near correct. For example if the enemy die is [1, 1, 5] then your die cannot contain a 5 or 6, and if it contains a 4 then the only other numbers allowed are 1 and 2. You'll need recursive backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> comb = [i for i in itertools.product(range(1, upper+1), repeat=len(enemy_die)) 
>         if sum(i)== sum(enemy_die)]
>
> for die in comb:
>     if win(die, enemy_die):
>         return list(die)
> return []
> ```

There's an early return -- but it's after creating the entire list of possibilities. Changing `comb` to a generator expression will let you skip generating the rest of the `comb` after finding a winner:

```
enemy_die_sum = sum(enemy_die)  # Might as well cache this too

comb = (i for i in itertools.product(range(1, upper + 1), repeat=len(enemy_die))
        if sum(i) == enemy_die_sum)
```

You can then fold the `win()`-checking loop into the same expression, simplifying down to this (thanks @Mathias Ettinger):

```
def winning_die(enemy_die):
    upper_bound = max(enemy_die) + 1
    enemy_die_sum = sum(enemy_die)

    comb = (die for die in itertools.product(range(1, upper_bound + 1), repeat=len(enemy_die))
            if sum(die) == enemy_die_sum and win(die, enemy_die))

    return list(next(comb, []))
```

For me, this runs around 10-50x faster for your test cases.

Comment: If you add `and win(i, enemy_die)` at the end of the genexpr, you can then just `return next(comb, [])` without having to do the looping in Python and possibly gain some more time too.

Comment: Thank you very much,  DenC and Mathias. But it is still not fast enough to pass the game :-(.